# Prevent IE users from loading a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, css, internet-explorer

I'm a C++ developer trying to deliver his first PHP/HTML5/CSS3 project. I was not familiar with browser compatibility issues (especially IE) and I was doing my CSS stuff on linux box. Now project is done and ready to deliver but found that no CSS code works on IE.

Googling around I found IE7.js, CSS3 Pie and other java script tricks but no one did successfully resolve all issues. So I'm trying to find a way to prevent users from loading content with old IE versions.

This script (or conditional comment) should redirect users to a custom page that indicates they must download and install IE 10 or above, or a modern browser.

I tried putting this code at the end of page:

```
<!--[if IE]>
 <?php 
 header( 'Location: http://www.foo-bar.com/please-use-a-browser.html' ) ; 
 ?>
<![endif]-->
```

But didn't redirect.

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Users don't understand what a "browser" is and will never blame it for the reason they can't access your website, nor will they upgrade (even if they knew how, they may not be able to).  They will simply take their business elsewhere.  As far as they're concerned, every other part of the internet works fine for them and the programmer (you) is the one to blame.

Comment: @cimmanon Sure. But I prefer to lose some users until I fix IE issues, rather than having disappointed users (When they see a disaster in site design, how can they trust us? ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you put at the end of the page wont work because it is calculated on the client side and PHP is a server side language. So, when the client resolves whether the user is using IE...nothing happens because the PHP hasnt output any 'instructions' for runtime which the browser can read and understand.

Replace `header( 'Location: http://www.foo-bar.com/please-use-a-browser.html' ) ;` with:

```
<script>
     window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
</script>
```

So your code will be:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script>
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also, put it at the top of the page- there is no need to process the previous content before redirecting, whether to continue should be the first thing ascertained in the `<head>` section.

That said, my general inclination would be to debug and work through the CSS issues, especially as IE 10 [dropped support for conditional comments](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/) and can hold its own pretty well, you may find you are merely putting off the inevitable (sorry to be the bearer of bad news!)

An alternative, would be to put the following in the `head` section of your page:

```
<script>
    navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
</script>
```

If you really want to be certain, [read this article from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about detecting IE

Comment: Of course I would like all users to see the shiny css design but I can't do css/js hacks in the first place. I'm gonna disable IE and force everybody to use firefox+chrome+safari, after solving issues, I'll remove redirection script.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false)){
     header('Location: http://www.foo-bar.com/please-use-a-browser.html');
     exit(0);
}
```

On the server side.